# Querying hierarchical data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

### How do you write a recursive SQL query that shows the diffrent levels of hierachical relationship as individual results?

---

I have a table in my database (`Container`) that has a hierarchical relationship with itself (any container can have many inner containers). I’m trying to create a view that shows each container with all of its outers (not just its immediate outer) along with how many levels deep the inner container is. For example:

If my Container table had the following records in it:

- Id: 1 outerId: null
- Id: 2    outerId: 1
- Id: 3    outerId: 1
- Id: 4    outerId: 2
- Id: 5 outerid: 4

I would want the view to show:

- innerId: 2  outerId:1   lvl:1
- innerId: 3  outerId:1   lvl:1
- innerId: 4  outerId:1   lvl:2
- innerId: 4  outerId:2   lvl:1
- innerId: 5   outerId:1         lvl:3
- innerId: 5   outerId:2         lvl:2
- innerId: 5   outerId:4         lvl:4

NOT

- Id: 2     Path: 1
- Id: 3     Path: 1
- Id: 4     Path: 1,2
- Id: 5     Path: 1,2,4

Basically, I want to be able to find out what inner containers are inside of a specific container by executing: `select innerId from v_MyView where outerId = @outer_id`  and find out what containers a specific container is in by executing: `select outerId from v_MyView where innerId = @inner_id`

### ***Update***

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I'm pretty familer with recursive CTEs. The issue that I am having is not that I don't know how to write a recursive CTE, but rather that the I need the output to be in multiple rows rather than a concatinated field in the view.

This is what I already have:

```
with MYCTE as
(
    select 
         Id, 
         Cast(null as varchar(max)) as cntr_path,
         0 as lvl
      from Container
      where Container.outerId is null
    union all
    select 
        Container.Id,
        IsNull(cntr_path + ',','') + '[' + cast(Container.outerId as varchar(max)) + ']',
        lvl + 1
      from Container join MYCTE 
        on Container.outerId = MYCTE.Id
)
select * from MYCTE where cntr_path is not null
```

but this produces only one row per inner container. What I am wanting is one row per inner container per outer container

I guess the best way to describe the view that I want is as a "linking table" that links every outer container with every one of their inners - with both the "outerId" and the "innerId" acting like foreign keys (both pointing to Id in Container).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can easily done using a recursive common table expression (supported by all modern DBMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping on it for a bit, I realized that I had misidentified the anchor of my recursive CTE. Rather than the outermost containers being my anchor (as in my updated example), the anchor should be every container with an outer:

```
select 
     Id as InnerId, 
     Container.outerId as OuterId
     1 as lvl
  from Container
```

which makes the recursive portion of my CTE:

```
union all
select 
    MYCTE.InnerId,
    Container.OuterId
    lvl + 1
  from Container join MYCTE 
    on Container.Id = MYCTE.OuterId
  where Container.OuterId is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, then check out this [Microsoft link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).  It details Recursive Common Table Expressions in great detail.

In Oracle, here is a link that describes [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

MySQL [hierarchical queries](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The examples given in the articles will give you the necessary stepping stones to resolve your issue.